# Change the color of every n-element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a for-loop which looks like this

```
for(i=1; i<= json.tracks.length; i++) {
$('<li>'+ json.tracks[i].name + '</li>').appendTo('#results'); }
```

On default it run's 100 times and I want to apply a sequence of color's to it

```
i = 1 --> red  
i = 2 --> green  
i = 3 --> blue  
i = 3 --> black  
i = 4 --> yellow  
i = 5 --> orange  

i = 6 --> red  
i = 7 --> green  
i = 8 --> red  
...  
...
```

I tried to jquery's **:nth-child()** function and a modulator but both didn't really worked.

Is there a nice way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store an array for all the colors and take the `array.length` modulo of `i`:

```
var colors = ['red','green','blue','black','yellow','orange'];
for(i=0; i<json.tracks.length; i++) {
    var idx = i % colors.length;
    $('<li />').text(json.tracks[i].name)
        .css('color',colors[idx])
        .appendTo('#results');
}
```

Comment: @MariusFeldmann: Don't forget to mark as answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class in the same loop action using the modulus `i % 5`:

```
for(i=1; i<= json.tracks.length; i++) {
  $('<li>'+ json.tracks[i].name + '</li>').appendTo('#results').addClass("color" + i % 5); 
}
```

This will add a class to each new `<li>` as in `class="color0"` through `class="color4"`

Then define in your CSS, color classes to whatever colors you wish them to be.  The benefit of using a class is that you can modify other CSS properties as well.

```
.color0 {
  color: red;
  /* these are bold too, for some reason */
  font-weight: bold;
}
.color1 {
  color: green;
}
.color2 {
  color: blue;
}
...
.color4 {
  color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-child()` will work fine. You have to use it like

```
li:nth-child(xn+y)
```

where `x` would mean *every xth child* and `y` is the element you start from.

It's also a CSS3 selector, so you don't even have to use JavaScript for that (but it won't work in IE before IE9).

Example:

```
li:nth-child(6n+1) {
    color: red;
}

li:nth-child(6n+2) {
    color: green;
}

li:nth-child(6n+3) {
    color: blue;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gRdMS/)

---

Using it together with jQuery will work fine as well:

```
$('li:nth-child(6n+1)').css('color', 'red');
```

or add the color directly when you create the elements, as shown in other answers. This is better as jQuery does not have to search for the elements again.

Comment: Flip side: it's a CSS3 selector, so older versions of IE won't be supported. (Plus, he's using JavaScript to build the list anyway.)

Comment: @mblase75: Right, it won't work in <IE9 ... maybe this answer is still useful to someone in the future where all browsers support it ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to put the colors in an array, then let the iteration of the loop figure out which color to add to the LI, like so:

```
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "orange", "black", "yellow"];
for(i=1; i<= 100; i++) {
   $('#results').append('<li style="background: '+colors[i % colors.length]+'">' + json.tracks[i] + '</li>');
}
```

You can see my example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/fwzhB/

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

one simple but brash suggestion use an element id of the same numeric value

```
$('<li id=" '+ i  +'">'+ json.tracks[i].name + '</li>').appendTo('#results');
```

with css for each li elements comprising colors or even put the colors in an array's key value pairs

x[0] = "red"...
.
.

and

```
$('<li style="color: '+ x[i]  +'">'+ json.tracks[i].name + '</li>').appendTo('#results');
```

but as mentioned previusly it only gets the job done and are pathetic from a coding perspective